# Install .iso file on a remote server without DVD drive access

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, disk-image

Is there an easy way to install software located on a .iso file to a remote server which does not provide to me access to the DVD Drive?

I have a license for SQL Server 2008 Web Edition through WebsiteSpark and need to install it on my remote VPS using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) allows you to open an ISO file and extract its contents as if it were a zip file.

Answer (score 4):

Not always the best solution but remote desktop allows you to use your local cd/dvd drives (and virtual cd drives) as if they were local to the remote server. Check your remote desktop preferences to enable this.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 2):

You know Microsoft gives away a Virtual CD driver? Easy to use and lets you mount any ISO to look just like any other drive.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe

Comment: I don't think this is available anymore :(

Comment: I fear you're correct. Damned shame.

Answer (score 1):

[Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/home) will let you assign a drive letter to an ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any program that can extract the contents of the ISO file, or alternatively, can mount the ISO file in a virtual CD\DVD drive. MagicISO or ISOBuster are two of the programs that I use.